# How to find indirect dependency of a externally build debian package

Tags: dependencies, debian-based

Unable to find the indirect dependencies of internal built debian package, as with apt and dpkg are only able to find the dependency of locally installed packages like vim etc not working on the external .deb package.

Comment: Decide a libc6 version, example : `$ objdump -x [executable or shared library] | grep GLIBC_2` ............ and other dependencies `$ dpkg-shlibdeps -t [executable]` : A folder `debian/` with an empty file 'control' is required. (The system libc6 version will be listed.)